# App stuck on Launch Screen when migrating

Tags: objective-c, migration, launch-screen, xcdatamodel, hockeyapp

I am performing a lightweight migration on an app.

I am using hockeyapp for distribution and when I update the app through that website the app stays on the Launch Screen for 20 seconds and then the iPad terminates the app with the error: "xxx failed to scene-create after 13.21s (launch took 6.79s of total time limit 20.00s)". After that the app launches with the same behavior and does not go any further.

What I have noticed when running from version 1 -> 2:

1) When I run through simulator everything goes fast and works fine.

2) When I run through iPad connected to the computer the app stays on Launch Screen for 5 seconds and then takes 30 seconds to migrate and everything works fine.

I do not perform the migration on the main thread.

Does anyone have idea how I can find out what is wrong and how I can debug through the launch screen?

Any help appreciated

Comment: The distribution method doesn't matter, as the exact code is installed on your device that you upload to HockeyApp. Downloading and installing the app is fully handled by iOS. Use Instruments when running it on your iPad to see which of your code takes how long.

Comment: thanks, the problem was that hockey app didn´t update the identifier on the old data model, and hence the problem only occurred with hockeyapp

Comment: I am not sure I understand how this could be related to HockeyApp as its SDK has no code or knowledge to somehow interact with any of your data models. This is code that you would have to implement yourself. HockeyApp only distributes the binary that you provide with the code that you write.